# How to get last login ip from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get last login ip according to my data.

Example my current data

```
----------------------------------------
id uid  ip            date
-----------------------------------------
1  3    192.168.1.1   2010-11-22 22:25:39
2  3    192.168.1.8   2010-11-23 22:28:12
3  3    192.168.1.3   2010-11-24 00:01:30
4  3    192.168.1.5   2010-11-25 00:20:25
```

How to get the **`id 3`** as the last login ip?

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM ip_address WHERE uid='3'";
```

Comment: Note that the last user to login is id 4, not id 3.

Comment: I want the `id 3` as last login ip and `id 4` is current login ip :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select ip from ip_address order by date desc limit 0,1;
```

...Will return the last IP.

```
select * from ip_address order by date desc limit 0,1;
```

...Will return the whole record.

Comment: it will return to `id 4`. I want the `id 3` as a last login ip. let me know

Comment: Apologies; the first character is the offset. Try limit 0,1

Comment: add the `WHERE uid=3` and you're set

Comment: hmm.. still display **`id 4`** as last login ip.

Comment: @nos -- if so, then I fundamentally misunderstood the question. Adding "where uid=3" will always return uid=3, regardless of who logged in last. The poster is asking that uid be returned *given the sample data*; not in general.

Comment: That's because the last IP to login *is* uid 4; look at your timestamps. uid3 logged in at 1 a.m., uid4 logged in at 8 p.m. So, using limit 1,1 will give you uid3 because it's the second last, offset by 1 (the first value before the comma).

Comment: @nos -- apologies, I got confused about what you were saying in the above comment. Adding WHERE uid = 3 is necessary if there are values in that table with uid not = 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `ip_address` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

EDIT: there should be back ticks on at least date, preferably ip_address too.

EDIT 2: There we go.

Comment: This will return the entire list except in descending order; the poster asked for just the last IP.

Comment: I fixed it a few mins ago, after I realized that :P

Comment: Preferably? Why? It's useless (and pretty annoying to be honest). It's not even required on date, MySQL allows the use of some keyword as column names (even `CREATE TABLE date (date date);` would work correctly).

Comment: Annoying? I can't stand it without the ticks. It is probably just a style preference thing for me. I used to run into issues with fields called 'Order' and such when I was first learning, and just got into the habit of using them.

Comment: @Josh : Well, you shouldn't use keywords as column/table/database/etc names. And yeah, I guess it's a matter of preference, because I can't stand it **with** the ticks!

Comment: Yes, I've long since abandoned bad table naming, now that I've had a few college level DB classes. :)